# How to write Regex that must contain at least 3 letters and 3 digits in any order?

Tags: regex

I have tried a regular expression that accepts 3 digits in any order and hopefully it worked.
Here is my example code:

```
^(?:\D*\d){3}\D*$
```

It accepts strings like this: abc123, a2v1c3, 123agc

My problem now is when I combine the code that accepts at least 3 letters and 3 digits. I have tried many combination of regular expression but I have failed to achieve the correct regular expression. Does anyone knows how to write the correct Regex that accepts at least 3 letters and 3 digits in any order? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you want 3 digits and "at least" 3 letters in any order this should work `^[A-Za-z]*(?:\d[A-Za-z]*){3,}$`

Comment: can you give some `falsey` examples?

Comment: Chase, this are list of false values: aa, 11, 1a2a, aa11, 11aa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use combinatorial lookaheads to ensure that at least three of each class is satisfied without consumption.  Then, consume all valid characters with the limit.

```
/(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z].*)(?=.*\d.*\d.*\d.*)[a-z0-9]{6,}/
```

It's ugly, but it's a lot prettier than the only alternative I could come up with;

```
/\d{3}[a-z]{3}|\d{2}[a-z]{3}\d|\d{1}[a-z]{3},\d{2} ...
```

Comment: Thanks Explosion Pills this works on my code (?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z].*)(?=.*\d.*\d.*\d.*)[a-z0-9]{6,}. I have tested it on http://regexr.com?33v68 and it work perfectly. Many thanks to all of you guys.

Comment: Can be simplified to `/(?=(?:.*[a-z]){3})(?:.*\d){3}/`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with two positive lookaheads:

```
/(?=(?:.*\d){3})(?=(?:.*[a-z]){3})^[a-z\d]*$/
```

[Regex101 Live Example](https://regex101.com/r/Vd4y5c/1)

---

## Breakdown:

**Look for at least 3 digits:**

```
(?=(?:.*\d){3})
```

**Look for at least 3 letters:**

```
(?=(?:.*[a-z]){3})
```

**Define what is allowed between the start and end:**

```
^[a-z\d]*$/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that for something like that, you would need to have some counting functionality, which if I remember correctly, *is not* provided by a regular expression engine (except for the usual `{min, max}` operator).

What you could do would be to have 2 regular expressions, one for letters and one for numbers (most programming languages provide a `isDigit` and `isLetter` functionalities so you can also use those) and have some sort of counter. Doing this instead of a regular expression will yield cleaner more maintainable and understandable code.

Comment: I agree, doing it with regex is a bad plan.