# Lookahead acting like it's consuming

Tags: javascript, regex

Yesterday I answered a question, [where the user was trying to match character classes "in any order."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151300/how-to-write-regex-that-must-contain-at-least-3-letters-and-3-digits-in-any-orde/15151579#15151579)  Regex has no "and" construct per se, but I came up with the solution (abridged):

```
(?=[a-z])(?=\d)[a-z\d]{6,}
```

This doesn't work as such, but changing it to

```
(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)[a-z\d]{6,}
```

*does* work.  Since lookaheads don't consume anything, I find this wildcard requirement to be a little strange.  Why are the `.*` needed to make this expression match, for example, `a1a1a1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wildcard is needed so that the lookahead can mean "anywhere ahead" rather than "right here, in the forward direction".

Without it, your regex is like this:

- Find somewhere in the string (call it X) where the following is true:
- The character after X is a letter
- The character after X is also a number
- There are 6 or more alphanumeric characters after X

Since the middle two are mutually exclusive (a character can not be a letter AND a number) it will always fail.

However, the second regex says:

- Find somewhere in the string (call it X) where the following is true:
- After an arbitrary number of characters, there is a letter
- After an arbitrary number of characters, there is a number
- There are at least 6 alphanumeric characters after X

Hopefully this explains the difference ;)

Comment: Ah, it would sometimes work for `(?=[a-z])(?=.*\d)`, I guess when the string started with an `a`.  So obvious once you think about it!