# Regex match at least 3 letters

Tags: regex

I need a regex to match

- at least 3 letters
- min length: 3
- may also contain `[0-9_-]` if there are 3 letters in string already (true if `str1`, `str_`, `str-`,
  `---------str`, `-s-t-r-` but false if `123`, `---`, `___`, `123---`, `123___`, `---___`)

I did this `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z_-].*)(?=.*\d.*)[\w]{3,}$` but it doesn't match strings like `str1`, `1str`, `str-`, `str_`.

Comment: `may contain [0-9_-] if there are 3 letters already` ahh, what does this mean exactly. Show some examples.

Comment: Please add several matching and non-matching examples of the desired behavior.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151300/how-to-write-regex-that-must-contain-at-least-3-letters-and-3-digits-in-any-orde

Comment: Oh, you mean something like this `^(?=(?:[^0-9_-]*[a-zA-Z]){3})[\w-]{3,}$`

Comment: @PM77-1 i don't need **at least 3 digits**

Comment: You need at least three letters - so look at the example I linked to and **learn** how to use positive lookahead.

Comment: @sln it doesn't match `-str` or `_str`

Comment: How do these terms come? One by one or are they in a long string?

Comment: `@sln it doesn't match -str or _str` Because `may contain [0-9_-] if there are 3 letters in string already`, better get it together man ..

Comment: A big -1 for you and I'm voting to close. Your original was `may contain [0-9_-] if there are 3 letters in string already (true if str1, str_, str-,`, don't change it after the fact and make fools out of people !!

Comment: @sln you asked to improve my question and I did it.

Comment: @sln I didn't changed the main logic of a question by the way. Look at answer I choosed and think why other people understood. Sorry for wasting your time

Comment: What you meant ? `^(?i)(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){3}))[\w-]{3,}$`

Comment: @sln that was my try to solve my problem

Comment: `if there are 3 letters in string already`

Comment: @sln my regex wasn't enough for solvimg my problem and I asked here

Comment: Even though you've been corrected, `if there are 3 letters in string already` Verbs and nouns and adjectives mean something in language, it's syntactical.

Comment: @sln yeah, English isn't my native. May I ask on stack however?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matches what you need:

```
([0-9_-]*[a-z][0-9_-]*){3}
```

Matches:

```
str1
str_
1str
str-
```

Does not match:

```
123
---
___
123---
123___
---___
```

Do these terms come alone or are they separated by spaces, commas?

If they come one by one, you should use enclose that regex between ^ and $.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `[0-9_-]*[a-zA-Z]{3,}[0-9_-]*`. This assumes that your string must have at least 3 letters.